# Why does the image extracted from the Project Tango Tablet appear gray?

Tags: c++, c, google-project-tango

- I am using the Project Tango C API
- I am writing the entire buffer pointed to by TangoImageBuffer.data to a file.

  ```
  // open a file
  std::fstream f(app.getNextFileName(), std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);

  // write the entire stride * height * 4 buffer into the file
  f.write((const char *) tango_image_buffer->data, 
      tango_image_buffer->stride * buffer->height * 4 * sizeof(uint8_t)
  );

  f.close();
  ```
- I then export the file to my PC and visualize it using python-opencv and numpy:

  ```
  import sys

  import cv2
  import numpy as np

  # dimensions of the image
  stride    = 1280
  width     = 1280
  height    = 720

  # I am using 3 channels so that the resulting image is not
  # transluscent
  channels  = 3

  input_filename  = sys.argv[1]
  output_filename = sys.argv[2]

  # load the image buffer into a list
  data = np.fromfile(input_filename, dtype=np.uint8)

  # create a height x width x channels matrix with the datatype uint8 
  # and all elements set to zero
  img = np.zeros((height, width, channels), dtype=np.uint8);

  # map elements in array to image matrix
  for y in range(0, height):    
      for x in range(0, width):
          img[y, x, 0] = data[y * stride + x + 2] #blue
          img[y, x, 1] = data[y * stride + x + 1] #green
          img[y, x, 2] = data[y * stride + x + 0] #red

  # display and save the resulting image
  cv2.namedWindow("tango-rgba")
  cv2.imshow("tango-rgba", img)
  cv2.waitKey(0)
  cv2.destroyAllWindows()
  cv2.imwrite(output_filename, img)
  ```
- Unfortunately, the resulting image [looks gray](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRpq2PGr-EIX0NYQWwzRElhRDQ/view?usp=sharing)
- The image only **appears** to be gray. Upon closer inspection of the pixels, you will find that the red, green, and blue components of the pixels are [different](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRpq2PGr-EIcm1hX3pZbkh4Q3RyQ0o1S0VfZ05OZmROeVpR/view?usp=sharing).
- EDIT: I have changed this post to specify that the buffer I am using is in RGBA8888 format. From the Project Tango Reference, "Only RGBA 8888 is provided"
- EDIT: It actually seems RGBA8888 format is not used. rhashimoto suggests that the format is YV12.
- EDIT: The image format is actually NV21 (See answer below).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Size of data field in TangoImageBuffer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31280824/size-of-data-field-in-tangoimagebuffer)

Comment: The documentation saying "Only RGBA 8888 is provided" is out of date, unfortunately. The format is now YV12. Your code would actually not read a RGBA8888 image correctly as it only moves 1 byte from one pixel to the next, but coincidentally this bug produces something that looks like an image when applied to YV12.

Comment: @rhashimoto Actually, [this piece of code](https://bpaste.net/show/72260f184a1c) is showing me that the format is [NV21](https://bpaste.net/show/7959a1fb0984). Is there any reason why this output could be wrong? The `tango_image_buffer` object is passed in via the `onFrameAvailable` [callback function](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/apis/c/reference/group/camera#tangoservice_connectonframeavailable).

Comment: The format tag is the safest method, so if it says NV21 I'd believe that. Here's the [post](https://plus.google.com/107000393284585119717/posts/Q9etEwrWWrs) from April that discusses the changing image formats.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that as of writing this post, the Project Tango Reference really is incorrect.

**The image format is NV21.**

```
char format_str[100] = {0};

switch (tango_image_buffer->format)
{
  case TANGO_HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_RGBA_8888:
        sprintf(format_str, "%s", "RGBA8888");
        break;
  case TANGO_HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YV12:
        sprintf(format_str, "%s", "YV12");
        break;
  case TANGO_HAL_PIXEL_FORMAT_YCrCb_420_SP:
        sprintf(format_str, "%s", "NV21");
        break;
  default:
        break;

}
__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, "Capture Info",
        "stride: %u, width: %u, height: %u, timestamp: %lf, frame: %llu, format: %s",
        tango_image_buffer->stride, 
        tango_image_buffer->width, 
        tango_image_buffer->height,
        tango_image_buffer->timestamp, 
        tango_image_buffer->frame_number, 
        format_str);
```

The output of the above piece of code is:

```
   V/Capture Info﹕ stride: 1280, width: 1280, height: 720, timestamp: 22157.368703, frame: 0, format: NV21
```

Here is my new visualization code in python using opencv and numpy:

```
import sys

import cv2
import numpy as np

input_filename  = sys.argv[1]
output_filename = sys.argv[2]


# dimensions of the image
stride    = 1280
width     = 1280
height    = 720
channels  = 4

# load file into buffer
data = np.fromfile(input_filename, dtype=np.uint8)

# create yuv image
yuv = np.ndarray((height + height / 2, width), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=data)

# create a height x width x channels matrix with the datatype uint8 for rgb image
img = np.zeros((height, width, channels), dtype=np.uint8);

# convert yuv image to rgb image
cv2.cvtColor(yuv, cv2.COLOR_YUV2BGRA_NV21, img, channels)

# display and save the resulting image
cv2.namedWindow("tango-rgba")
cv2.imshow("tango-rgba", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite(output_filename, img)
```

and the [resulting image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRpq2PGr-EIcFB5YXF4T1dFTlU/view?usp=sharing).

TLDR: The image format is NV21. OpenCV provides functionality for converting NV21 to RGB. The [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzRpq2PGr-EIcFB5YXF4T1dFTlU/view?usp=sharing) looks great.

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Works great. Only had to use ```yuv = np.ndarray((int(height + height / 2), width), dtype=np.uint8, buffer=data)```. Probably depending on the python version (I use python 3.6).